# Unable to run a Python code with Exscript - ImportError: No module named resource (CentOS 6.9)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install and run a python script for logging into my network devices. I have installed it in one of our instances (CentOS release 6.9). But when I try to run the script, i get an error. Here's what I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Exscript.util.interact import read_login    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Exscript.Queue       import Queue    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/Queue.py", line 40, in <module>
    from Exscript.util.decorator import get_label    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/util/decorator.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Exscript.protocols.Exception import LoginFailure    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Exscript.protocols.SSH2 import SSH2    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/SSH2.py", line 34, in <module>
    from paramiko.resource      import ResourceManager    
ImportError: No module named resource
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here to be honest. Here's the script:

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login    
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2    
account = read_login()    
conn = SSH2()    
conn.connect('x.x.x.x')    
conn.login(account)    
conn.execute('terminal pager 0')    
conn.execute(show IP)    
print conn.response    
conn.close
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue after installing Exscript v2.3.2 with "pip install Exscript"

In the original source code on github the file `Exscript/protocols/SSH2.py` for v2.3.2 does not contain this line so have you tried commenting it out?  That worked for me ..
Another option is to install Exscript from github and do make install

```
Comment out line 34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/SSH2.py:

#from paramiko.resource      import ResourceManager
```